# TypeError: Unable to obtain function signature

Tags: python

Iam using python-iminuit for minimizing variables. My code is given below:-

---

```
     from iminuit import describe,Minuit

     In [32]: class test:
                def f(x,y):
                  return x*y
     In [32]: ff=test()
     In [33]: m=Minuit(ff.f(1,1),x=2,error_x=.3,limit_(1,5),y=2,error_y=.3,limit_y(1,5))
     In [34]: describe(f)
     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-34-869682646e5a> in <module>()
     ----> 1 describe(f)
     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iminuit/util.pyc in describe(f, verbose)
     161         :ref:`function-sig-label`
     162     """
     --> 163     return better_arg_spec(f, verbose)
     164 
     165 

     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/iminuit/util.pyc in better_arg_spec(f,verbose)
      151             print "fail parsing __doc__"
      152 
      --> 153     raise TypeError("Unable to obtain function signature")
      154     return None
      155 

      TypeError: Unable to obtain function signature
```

---

I am new to python. I dont understand what it means.Can anyone explain what is the cause of this error?

Comment: What is assigned to `f`?  My guess is you mean to be `describe`ing `test.f` or `ff.f`.

Comment: Both are same .....right? 'ff' is an object of 'test' class

Comment: `ff` is an instance of `test`, yeah, though that doesn't make them the "same", nor does it make `test.f` and `ff.f` have the same signature (one is a bound method, the other is unbound).  But `f` is not assigned any value I can see in the code you provided here.

Comment: It is not taking any values.It produces an error "TypeError: f() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: _what is assigned to `f`_?  That's what will explain the specific error.  But it looks like you actually want to `describe` the method `ff.f` anyway.  And as to the exception, in Python, member methods (like `test.f`) have to take `self` as an explicit first argument.  As written, the instance that `f` is called on is being bound to `x`, so when you try to call it later with 2 arguments, the function is getting passed 3 arguments (including the instance, which is being bound to `x`).

Comment: This question is about iminuit and by now there's a stackoverflow tag for this. Could someone with the required karma please add that tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your code example contains a few errors and you didn't really say what you want to do. Assuming you want to find the minimum `(x, y)` point of the function `f(x, y) = x * y` in the range `x = (1, 5)` and `y = (1, 5)` using [iminuit](https://github.com/iminuit/iminuit), this is how to do it:

```py
from iminuit import Minuit

def f(x, y):
    return x * y

m = Minuit(f, pedantic=False, print_level=0,
           x=2, limit_x=(1,5),
           y=2, limit_y=(1,5))

_ = m.migrad()  # run the minimizer
print(m.values)  # show the result
```

This gives a result very close to the true solution `(x, y) = (1, 1)`:

```py
>>> print(m.values)  # show the result
{'y': 1.0000000000293232, 'x': 1.0000000000293232}
```